# Xamarin Android "Permission Denied" al guardar un bitmap

Tags: android, xamarin

Tengo un bitmap que quiero almacenar en el dispositivo (ya sea interna o externamente) funcionaba correcto, pero al intentar guardar me marca el siguiente error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/imagen.png" is denied.
```

Aquí es donde intento guardarlo:

```
var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "imagen.png");
var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
img.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
stream.Close();
```

Donde img es el bitmap.

Ya he habilitado los permisos con:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Pero sigue sin dejarme guardar en esa ruta, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola @Erik imagino que "funcionaba correcto" porque usabas un dispositivo con sistema operativo menor a 6.0, para OS 6.0 los permisos se deben pedir manualmente.

Comment: Hola! De hecho uso 6.0, cómo puedo pedirlos manualmente?

Comment: ese es el problema, agregué un ejemplo de como realizarlo, te sugiero veas en la documentación también :)

Answer (score -1):

El problema que indicas

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException

es debido a que debes recordar que desde Android 6.0, la petición de [permisos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) como :

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

[debe ser realizada manualmente en tiempo de ejecución](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) y no es suficiente con declarar los permisos en el archivo `Manifest.xml`.

Revisa la [documentación oficial](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) donde se encuentra un ejemplo de esto.

---

Agrego un ejemplo de como realizar la petición de los permisos `WriteExternalStorage` y `ReadExternalStorage` en `Xamarin`:

```
     //Define permisos requeridos por aplicación.
  readonly string [] PermissionsMyApp = 
    {
      Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
      Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
    };

    const int RequestExternalStorageId = 0;

    const string permission = Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage;
    if (CheckSelfPermission(permission) == (int)Permission.Granted)
    {
      //Ya se cuenta con permisos!
      return;
    }


     //Se necesita obtener permiso,
      if (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
      {
        //Explica al usuario porque necesita el permiso.
        Snackbar.Make(layout, "Permiso requerido para el correcto funcionamiento de la aplicación.", Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                .SetAction("OK", v => RequestPermissions(PermissionsMyApp, RequestExternalStorageId ))
                .Show();
        return;
      }

  //Finalmente requiere el permiso  permissions and Id
  RequestPermissions(PermissionsMyApp, RequestExternalStorageId);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo probaré, eso devuelve algún valor? o solamente me "activa" el permiso?? layout que es??

Comment: @EriK primero debes revisar si la aplicación cuenta con permisos, si no es así se abre una ventana de dialogo donde se pueden aceptar.

Comment: Lo he probado, y ya no me marca ningún error, pero al parecer no me guarda la imagen jejejeje

Comment: Revisa con un "File explorer" que tengas la imagen dentro de /storage/emulated/0/

Comment: Ya lo he checado pero nada :/ no me guarda la imágen

Comment: Revisa en los settings > Applications > selecciona tu aplicación y en Permissions verifica estén activados los permisos, para asegurar en verdad se realizo.

Comment: Si tiene los permisos, pero no me aparece la imagen